# Searching through a slice with a very large number of elements

Tags: go, slice

I worked on an API a little while back to keep records stored in two different systems in sync with each other. It's been working fine, but have run into an issue with a new table I'm bringing into sync that has a large number of records. Below is the basic premise.

table1 and table2 are a slice of structs that reflect the data that I'm trying to keep in sync. This works fine for around 20,000 records. But I'm working with 200,000 now and this doesn't feel very efficient, since I'm effectively running through every row potentially 200,000 times which results in billions of loops. Is there a more effective way to go about accomplishing this?

```
for _, item1 = range table1 {
    for _, item2 = range table2 {
        if item1.id == item2.id {
            itemsAreEqual = reflect.DeepEqual(item1, item2)
            if !itemsAreEqual {
               //Update Stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are the slices being populated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the order of elements in the tables is not important, use two maps instead:

```
for id1, item1:=range table1 {
   if item2, ok:=table2[id1]; ok {
     ...
   }
}
```

If you need to update `item1` and `item2` members, it might be better if you make these maps `map[idType]*Item` instead of `map[idType]Item`.

If the order is important, you can do the same with an array plus a map:

```
ids:=make(map[idType]*Item)
for i,item:=range table2 {
   ids[item.id]=&table2[i]
}
for id1, item1:=range table1 {
   if item2, ok:=ids[id1]; ok {
     ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Completely forgot to mark this as the best answer. Thanks. Don't know how I didn't think of that myself.